# Items not showing in spinner

Tags: android

i have a spinner element inside an alert dialog, but the items are not showing when i click on the spinner element. The dialog itself is working fine, the only problem is with the spinner.

```
 AlertDialog.Builder adb_spremeni = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
                        LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());                            
                        final View myView = li.inflate(R.layout.update_projekt_layout, null);
                        adb_spremeni.setView(myView);

                        adb_spremeni.setCancelable(false)
                                .setPositiveButton("Spremeni", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                        eNaslov = (EditText) myView.findViewById(R.id.spremeni_naslov);
                                        Spinner  sStanje = (Spinner) myView.findViewById(R.id.spremeni_stanje);
                                        String[] s = {"pomembno", "kriticno", "nujno"};

                                        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(myView.getContext(),
                                                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, s);

                                        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                                        sStanje.setAdapter(adapter);

                                        String pos = getItem(position).getId();
                                        String naslov = eNaslov.getText().toString();
                                        String spremeni_stanje = sStanje.getSelectedItem().toString();
                                        onItemClickInterface.getOnItemClickId("spremeniProjekt", naslov, spremeni_stanje, Long.valueOf(pos), "");
                                    }
                                })
                                .setNegativeButton("Prekliči", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                        dialogInterface.cancel();
                                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Preklical sem", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    }
                                });
                        AlertDialog alertDialog_spremeni = adb_spremeni.create();
                        alertDialog_spremeni.setCancelable(true);
                        alertDialog_spremeni.show();
```

Comment: set the adapter outside the onClick method itself

Comment: it worked, thank you.